# Name for topological spaces where "every point has a local base wellordered by reverse inclusion"?

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, soft-question, terminology

There are many properties regarding local bases of a topological space, like first countable if every point has a countable local base.

Is there a similar name for a space where "every point has a local base wellordered by reverse inclusion"?

That is, given $X=(X,\tau)$ topological space, we say $X$ has the property if for every $x\in X$ there exists $\mathcal{B}=\{B_i\}_{i\in\kappa}\subset\tau$ such that $B_i\subset B_j$ for every $j<i<\kappa$.

Does this property have any known consequence or relation with other properties?

Comment: My friend Robert Leek has done some work that includes looking at spaces with this property. I don't know how standard his terminology is, but he refers to them as "well-based spaces" (see Definition 2.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.6519.pdf).

Comment: Horst Herrlich has shown in [Quotienten geordneter Räume und Folgenkonvergenz](https://eudml.org/doc/214009) that pseudoradial spaces are exactly quotients of the spaces you describe.

Comment: If by well-ordered you really mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order, then this implies that every point has a minimal neighborhood. Such spaces are called "Alexandroff spaces" (not to be confused with Alexandrov spaces, i.e. of metric spaces with curvature bounds). See http://www.emis.de/journals/AMUC/_vol-68/_no_1/_arenas/arenas.pdf: Arenas, F.G.. "Alexandroff spaces.." Acta Mathematica Universitatis Comenianae. New Series 68.1 (1999): 17-25 and he refers to Alexandroff P.,Diskrete Räume, Mat.Sb.(N.S.)2(1937),501–518, for the first study of such spaces.

Comment: @ClemensSämann That would be if the neighbourhoods were well-ordered by *inclusion*. Cla asks for neighbourhood bases well-ordered by *reverse inclusion*. For instance, any metric space is an example, because we can use balls of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n$ a positive natural number. Please don't delete your comment, as others may have the same confusion.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I thought I checked what is meant but I mixed it up after all. Sure I let it stand as it is.

Comment: Thank you for the references. Those together with the answer below I think are enough to close the question.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202280.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that replacing "well-ordered" by "linearly-ordered" produces an equivalent property since any linear order contains a cofinal well order.
Such spaces were called *lob-spaces* and studied by S.W. Davis in [*Spaces with linearly ordered local bases*](http://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v03/tp03102.pdf), Topology proceedings 3, (1978), pp.37-51.

Comment: This paper seems really what I was looking for. Thank you, I'll take my time to read it.

Comment: I bet I can guess what the letters "lob" stand for ...

Comment: The same notion appears in N. Howes, [A note on transfinite sequences](https://doi.org/10.4064/fm-106-3-213-226), Fundamenta Mathematicae 106 (1980), 213-226, under the name "chain local base (CLB) space".